# Given a field symbol pointing to a table, how do I assign it to a structure field symbol?

Tags: abap

I have a field symbol `<lt_something>` which points to a table. This table has a single line as content. How do I assign that line in the table to a new field symbol, say `<ls_something>` ?

I tried :

```
READ TABLE <lt_something> INDEX 1 REFERENCE INTO <ls_something>.
```

But the above code dumps, what is the right approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up field symbols and data references. Use either

```
DATA lr_foo TYPE REF TO something.
READ TABLE lt_something INDEX 1 REFERENCE INTO lr_foo.
lr_foo->bar = 'baz'.
```

or

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <ls_foo> TYPE something.
READ TABLE lt_something INDEX 1 ASSIGNING <ls_foo>.
<ls_foo>-bar = 'baz'.
```

but do not merge the two ways.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your field symbol table is assigned before you perform your read? The general structure of your read table looks OK, but you should use ASSIGNING in your read statement:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lt_something> TYPE ANY TABLE,
               <ls_something> TYPE ANY.

" ... blah blah presume you did some work on <lt_something>...

IF <lt_something> IS ASSIGNED.

  READ TABLE <lt_something> INDEX 1 ASSIGNING <ls_something>.

  " Check sy-subrc or <ls_something> IS ASSIGNED.
  " Do work.

ENDIF.
```

Comment: You cannot use explicit or implicit index operations on tables with
types "HASHED TABLE" or "ANY TABLE". "<TAB>" has the type "ANY TABLE".
It is possible that the "TABLE" addition was not specified before
"<TAB>".

Answer (score 0):

The field-symbol needs to be the line type of the table, not the table itself.

```
DATA:  
     i_vbak            type standard table of vbak.

FIELD-SYMBOLS:  
     <i_vbak> type vbak.

READ TABLE i_vbak ASSIGNING <i_vbak>.
```

Comment: field-symbols:  <i_vbak>  type vbak.